# How to remove arrow in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on a `UITableView`. Please tell me how to remove the arrow button displayed in the each and every row?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, set the `accessoryType` property of your UITableViewCell to UITableViewCellAccessoryNone, *which is the default FYI*.

Comment: FWIW, default or not, I had this same question. It's probably getting set in Interface/Storyboard Builder, and/or perhaps (like in my case) I need some cells to indicate more detail and others not. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 14):

If you are using the interface builder just select your cell and set the `accessory` to `none`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For c# user :

```
UITableViewCell cell = new UITableViewCell(); 

cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//Write following code into your program


-(UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tv accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

//Create a table for different section of app

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}
```

// VKJ

Comment: accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath method is **not available on Swift**

Answer (score 2):

**for Swift 3**

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift**

Add following to end of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method just before 
`return`.

```
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
```

it just works perfect!!